# jQuery - pre-populate a droppable space with a draggable item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using the jQuery function of dragging and dropping.

Is there anyway to pre-populate a droppable space with a draggable item?

Thanks,

H.

Comment: Just create your HTML draggable elements inside your droppable element. Am I missing something?

Comment: As it happens, that is what I ended up doing - I thought there might be an 'easy' way inside jQuery.  Pop this down as your answer and I'll accept it etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information purposes, I ended up using a combination of PHP and HTML to achieve the desired result.